# webdriverio - how to get a LI texts into an array

Tags: javascript, cucumber, chai, webdriver-io

I started using webdriverio with cucumber this morning and everything was going good until I had to check if an element list (ul > li) contained a specific text. I started playing with: http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html

This is what I have so far:

```
@Then /^One error should be "([^"]*)"$/, (errorMessage, cb) ->
        that = @
        errors = []
        @client
            .elements '.ui .list > li', (err, res) ->
                _.forEach res.value, (item) ->
                    that.client
                        .elementIdText item.ELEMENT, (err, res) ->
                            errors.push(res.value)
```

My idea was try to save all the li's texts into an array that I could check later but because but I am kind of lost on what to do next.

Any help would be very appreciated .. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a selector to a property command matches multiple elements, it returns an array of results instead of a single one. So the easiest solution to check if a certain list element contains a string would be

```
client.getText('.ui .list>il', function(err, res) {
    var containsText = false;
    res.forEach(function(liText) {
        containsText |= liText.indexOf('some string') > -1;
    });
    containsText.toBe(true);
});
```

I am using a jasmine assertion here, so if you are using a different assertion lib, you need to adapt that.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately what is returned under res.value is an array of id elements not really the strings. So I need to use another asynchronous function (`that.client.elementIdText`) to return the actual text

Comment: this can't be true, check out https://gist.github.com/christian-bromann/fac72d21adb31fd6cafa

Comment: I apologize for my initial response. You were 100% right, I was over complicating my code your solution is way more cleaner! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After pulling a few more hairs out I came out with this solution:

```
    @Then /^One error should be "([^"]*)"$/, (errorMessage, cb) ->
        that = @
        @client
            .elements '.ui .list > li', (err, res) ->
                total = res.value.length
                errors = []

                for item in res.value
                    that.client
                        .elementIdText item.ELEMENT, (err, res1) ->
                            errors.push res1.value
                            if errors.length == total
                                if errors.indexOf(errorMessage) != -1
                                    cb(null, errors)
                                else
                                    cb("Expected error string: \"#{errorMessage}\" not found in: [#{errors}]")
```

I know it is not the most beautiful solution so if anyone out there can help me to make it better please let me know.

Thanks